# Case insensitive searching for words in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, mongoid, case-insensitive

Is there a way to set an attribute in mongoid for case insensitive searches?

Lets say that somebody has a username: IAmGreat and I want to find the users data using their unique username without butchering it and changing it to iamgreat.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just down a `User.login.downcase` (or whatever your model/attribute combination is) when making the comparison? This will leave the capitalization in the DB as-is, but downcase the field just for comparison.

Comment: If you store your usernames and emails downcased in the DB then is for sure the best solution. Much faster than a regex search!

Comment: @RobertReiz - sure, if that is an option for the OP. I was answering the question about how to do a comparison in cases where that may not be a choice.

Answer (score 51):

Actually you can search case insensitive. But you have to search with an regex!
Here is an example how I'm using it at http://zeit.io

```
User.where(email: /\A#{Regexp.escape(email)}\z/i).first
```

With the `/` you are starting and ending the regex. The `i` after the regex means case insensitive. `\A` Means the string has to start with the search string and `\z` means the string has to end with the search string. This is important if you are looking for an exact match.

Comment: FYI: you may need to sanitize your regex if it includes user input: `/^#{Regexp.escape(email)}$/i`

Comment: user = where(email: /^#{email}$/i).first

Comment: `/i` is the in trick `User.where(name: /.*#{term_to_search}.*/i).to_a` which ignore case in the given string

Comment: This now does not work. You can do the query without the conditions.

Answer (score 6):

You can even try something like:

```
User.where(username: /#{username}/i).first
```

Comment: (1) That doesn't check case-insensitive equality (2) That (AFAIK) won't use an index to check the collection so it can be very expensive.

Comment: Yeah. This is 50% slower than the default query. But it does check case-insensitive equality.

Comment: No it doesn't check equality. Your regex has no anchors.

Comment: Actually Mongoid **does** use indexes with regex queries, but it's limited.  To take the most advantage of an index with a regex search, have the regex start at the beginning of the string, like so:
`User.where(username: /^#{username}/i).first` (note the `^`)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using rails or mongoid you can try the ff:

`@user = User.where({:username => /.*#{name}.*/i })`

Comment: With this answer you might get multiple matches. That's actually not very good if you want to find a username. Assume you have 3 usernames like `bob`, `my_bob`, `bob_2`. If the input is simply `bob`, the regex above will return all 3 users because you are working with `.*`.

Answer (score 0):

If your application doesn't need to store user-input as case-sensitive, just convert the input to uppercase or lowercase on the way in.  Example,

```
username = params[:username].to_s.downcase
```

Otherwise, if performance is an issue for you (case-insensitive regex cannot take advantage for indexes) the right way to go about it is to store a backup field for username

```
field :username_downcase
```

And then do the query:

```
User.where(username_downcase: params[:username].to_s.downcase)
```